# Formula for Stereographic Projection of Ball of Radius $R$

Tags: stereographic-projections

Let the following be the set of points of radius $R$:
$$
B^n_R:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\,\,| \,\,||x||_2^2=R^2\}
$$
What is the formula to stereographically project $B_R^n$ to the $n$-dimensional hyperplane $E^n$?
$$
E^n:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\,\,| \,\,x_{n+1}=0\}
$$

---

So I'd do a stereographic projection from the north pole $(0,...,0,R)$ onto $E^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cartesian coordinates it's $(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})\to (\frac{Rx_1}{R-x_{n+1}},\dots,\frac {Rx_n}{R-x_{n+1}},0)$.

See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection).

Comment: @DavidK I took your advice.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to do the following projections:

1) Projection to unit sphere

2) Stereographic projection

3) Rescaling by radius R